# Nested git repositories that behave like one project with projectile

Tags: git, projectile

I am trying to understand how to use https://projectile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/#customizing-project-root-files but it is not clear yet.

My goal is to have nested git projects. Let's say I have a directory structure like /a/{b,c}. Folders a, b and c have been created using git clone and all contain a `.git` folder. From project a, I'd like to be able to use projectile-find-file over files of a, b and c.

Is it possible? Am I looking at the good documentation? Is it possible to enable this behavior only from one directory by using `.dir-locals.el`?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I m facing the same problem and was messing with projectile-project-root, trying to set it to .projectile (file that i would manually add to project roots) but somehow it still detects all the git projects.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't figure it out.

Comment: FWIW it looks to me as if adding `.git` to `projectile-project-root-files-top-down-recurring` and removing it from `projectile-project-root-files-bottom-up` will have the effect of making projectile keep checking the parent directory of any git root until it no longer finds a `.git` file.  This would mean that any directories *between* the real root and the submodule in question would also need to be submodules.  (But the documentation for these options is quite difficult to follow -- I can't tell how "top" and "bottom" are being defined, specifically.)

Comment: If there are no other `.dir-locals.el` files below the actual project root, then one with `((nil . ((projectile-project-root . "/path/to/project"))))` would also do the trick for file-visiting buffers at least.

Answer (score 1):

Same issues. Unfortunately, projectile switch project doesnt work for nested projectile projects. Or I cant get it to work,

One solution is to use helm-projectile-ag for example but prefix it
eg C-u M-x helm-projectile-ag

you are prompted for options so add "-u" (the ag flag to ignore .gitignore) and it will recursively search outside of the laws laid down in .gitignore. Unfortunately, it includes cache etc.